# Node - Read Specific Line and Delete Specific Line

Tags: node.js, fs

I've started looking at Nodes readline however I want to confirm is this possible:

```
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
                input: require('fs').createReadStream('helpers/available.txt')
});

lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
               console.log('Line from file:', line)
});
```

However on prints every line.

How do I just print line at line x

This should then allow me do things like iterate through the file - and hopefully once I've ready line at x, delete that line

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
                input: require('fs').createReadStream('helpers/available.txt')
});
var counter;
var val = 10;
lineReader.on('line', function (line, callback) {
                if(err){
                    callback(err);
                } else if (counter === val) {
                    console.log('Line from file:', line, "at ", val);
                } else {
                    callback(null);
                }
                counter++;

});
```

You could build a counter

Comment: How to delete a line from a `ReadStream`? Only a `WriteableStream` can be used for `readline.clearLine()`